# Python JSON decodes on part of the file

Tags: python, json, encoding

I am trying to decode, then parse a JSON file it's about 9MB.
But when I try to decode the json file, to make it into a python dictionary object I get the error:

> 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 3161744-3161747: invalid data

I think this might be because of encoding/decoding issues, but I'm not entirely certain. I don't know what the file is being encoding as because I am getting it from a third party, and unfortunately I can't show the file because it contains sensitive information.

Also, the people who supplied the JSON file said it's a valid JSON file and passes json lint.
Here is my code below:

```
import json

""" JSON Parser """
class parser:
    json_file = None

    """ The JSON File name"""
    def json_object(self, file):
        self.json_file = file

    """ Open up file and parse it """
    def json_encode(self):
        try:
            json_data = open(self.json_file)
            data = json_data.read().decode('utf8')
            result = json.loads(data)
        except Exception as e:
            result = e
        return result

""" Instantiate parser and begin parsing the file"""
p = parser()
p.json_object('file.js')
print p.json_encode()
```

Comment: Although the file may be formatted properly from a JSON point of view, it may still be invalid from a UTF-8 encoding point of view. You should be able to elicit the same error by reading the file as a UTF-8 text file, which would eliminate JSON from the problem. Are you certain the file is UTF-8 encoded and not something like ISO 8859-1?

Comment: @GregHewgill I am not certain, that's the problem, I can open it in a text-editor as utf-8 encoded then save it. Then when I run the parser I only get the last part of the json file encoded. The same problem occurs when I try in PHP. This is a very odd problem, however, I still think it has something to do with the way the file was encoded in the first place.

Comment: Can you read the file, then try `data[3161730:3161760]` to see what's causing the error?

Comment: @ThomasK thanks for that tip, don't know why I didn't try that, it seems to have weird characters like ê.  I got rid of them, but I still only get the very last part decoded out of a large file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you should be decoding the utf-8 before reading it in. Json should be transparent to the encoding as you might have some strings in the json that are utf-8 and others that are latin-9, etc. Try:

```
json.load(open(self.json_file))
```

Comment: I tried this already. The error I get is "'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 45-48: invalid data". I don't know how to check what characters are in those byte positions